# Show that not necessarily $p^5 \mid a(a + b) $.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

suppose p is an odd prime and $a$ and $b$ are positive integers such that $ p^5 \mid a^2 + b^2 $ and $ p^5 \mid a(a + b)^2$. Show that not necessarily $p^5 \mid a(a + b) $. I'm not getting anything productive

Comment: For there to be a difference between $a(a+b)^2$ and $a(a+b)$ the extra factor $a+b$ must be divisible by $p$. Meaning that $a\equiv -b$, and consequently $a^2+b^2\equiv 2a^2$. This means that both $a$ and $b$ must be divisible by $p$. Then write $a=pa_1$, $b=pb_1$, and see what follows.

Comment: or use $p\mid a(a+b)^2= a(a^2+2ab+b^2)\land p\mid a^2+b^2 \implies p\mid  2a^2b$

Comment: "For there to be a difference between $a(a+b)^2$ and $a(a+b)$ the extra factor $a+b$ must be divisible by p." I don't understand this

Comment: the answer i saw said that $p^3$ cannot divide $a + b$. I did not understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to find some values. For example p = 5, a = 25, b = 50